# SharePoint Online Modern Site- formating Table in multliline text column open in classic view

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have list in SharePoint modern site. When I copy and paste formated table from word to multline text column and save it. It open the multline column in classic view everytime. If I remove it , it open in modern look.

My clients requirement is to use formated table in content.

Can someone please guide how to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any option to add table from modern experience editor of multiline rich text columns.

I think this is a current limitation by Microsoft SharePoint:

[image]

So, if you want to add formatted tables to multiline rich text columns in SharePoint, you will have to use the classic experience editor of rich text columns.